# Android number in Electricity meter or speed meter view

Tags: android

I want to show the numbers in electricity meter view.

[image]

Want to show like above image.
Is there any library available? or give any example.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking questions.

Comment: Have every digit as a individual text area and use a function to cut up the number into digits (`txt1.setText(Math.Floor(x/1000000)`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electricity meter-like view - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133871/electricity-meter-like-view-android)

Comment: @Jonathan Twite. I already tried this and worked. But I cant control its height. That too high

Comment: `android:layout_height`?

Comment: @Jonathan Twite. I also tried this but it crops that view and not fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this help https://github.com/robinhood/ticker
Give it a try.